# HTML Canvas Image Not Showing Up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I coded a logo separately using HTML canvas. Now, I want to add it to the code of the site prototype I have. Problem is, whenever I try to add the code to the site, it never shows up. It leaves a big gaping space where the image *should* show up, but nothing else.

Here's the .js code for the logo I'm trying to add to the site:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.shadowColor = "black";
  context.shadowOffsetX = 5; 
  context.shadowOffsetY = 5; 
  context.shadowBlur = 6;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(150, 96, 50, 0, Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  var grd=context.createRadialGradient(90,100,3,90,40,100);
  grd.addColorStop(0.5,"33c3e3");
  grd.addColorStop(0,"a7eaf9");
  grd.addColorStop(1,"00cccc");

  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fill();

  context.font = "15px Georgia";
  context.fillStyle = "#003366";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText("Design This Site", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/3.5); 


  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(150, 60, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
  context.closePath();

  context.fillStyle = '#33c3e3';
  context.fill();
```

And here is the code of my site where it won't show up. (I've included the non-working .js under the "wrapper" class where I originally placed it when testing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyle.css">
</head>

<title>Prototype Contact Page</title>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="canvas2.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-item item1">

<nav>
<ul style="list-style-type:none">

   <li><a href="--">Home</a></li>

   <li><a href="--">About Me</a></li>

   <li><a href="--">Contact</a></li> 

 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>

<div class="flex-item item2">

<h3>Contact Me!</h3><hr><br>

 What's Your Name?<br>
<input type="text" name="flname" placeholder="First Name, Last Name">
 <br>

Email<br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@site.com">
<br>

 Reason for Contacting<br>
<input type="text" name="contactreason" placeholder="Reason for contacting me"><br>

 Your Message<br>
 <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20">Your message...</textarea><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"> |  <input type="reset">

 </form>
</div>

 <div class="flex-item item3">

<h4>New Site Updates!
<hr>
Portfolio Samples Added [10.14.2016]<br><br>
Links Added [10.14.2016]</h4>
</div>

</div>

 </html>
```

Comment: Any message in the console ? your script is found ?

Comment: Try putting the code inside a function `function myLogo(){ ...your code here }` then call that function via the onload event `window.addEventListener("load",myLogo)`

Comment: @Kaiido - I'm not seeing any messages. Just a blank area where the image should be. Not sure if my script is found.

Comment: You can check it by adding a `console.log('should run')` anywhere in your js file, or by looking at the networks panel of your [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Answer (score 0):

Put pound signs in front of your color codes like such:

```
grd.addColorStop(0.5,"#33c3e3");
grd.addColorStop(0,"#a7eaf9");
grd.addColorStop(1,"#00cccc");
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that at first! I added the pound signs, but the logo still doesn't seem to be showing up.

Comment: Hmm, it appears for me in this fiddle. I put the JS in a script tag and replaced your reference to canvas2.js. I do also see that you have a closing </form> tag but no opening one. Try getting rid of that maybe?

Comment: Would help if I attached the fiddle. :D

https://jsfiddle.net/wLrcmd67/